# How can I use python xlib to generate a single keypress?

Tags: python, xlib

I want to make a very simple python 3 script that will generate a single keypress (F15). I don't want to use a bunch of libraries to do this as I only need one key to be pressed and don't need support for the whole keyboard. I know I need to use KeyPress and KeyRelease in order to generate a keyboard event. I'm just not sure where exactly to start and the documentation is a little confusing.

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html
http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/?page=documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to show you how it could work, but porting it to [`python-xlib`](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) should be straightforward. So lets start with loading the library:

```
import ctypes
X11 = ctypes.CDLL("libX11.so")
```

and defining the structures needed:

```
class Display(ctypes.Structure):
    """ opaque struct """

class XKeyEvent(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ('type', ctypes.c_int),
            ('serial', ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('send_event', ctypes.c_int),
            ('display', ctypes.POINTER(Display)),
            ('window', ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('root', ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('subwindow', ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('time', ctypes.c_ulong),
            ('x', ctypes.c_int),
            ('y', ctypes.c_int),
            ('x_root', ctypes.c_int),
            ('y_root', ctypes.c_int),
            ('state', ctypes.c_uint),
            ('keycode', ctypes.c_uint),
            ('same_screen', ctypes.c_int),
        ]

class XEvent(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
            ('type', ctypes.c_int),
            ('xkey', XKeyEvent),
            ('pad', ctypes.c_long*24),
        ]

X11.XOpenDisplay.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Display)
```

Now we just need to send the event to the root window:

```
display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None)
key = XEvent(type=2).xkey #KeyPress
key.keycode = X11.XKeysymToKeycode(display, 0xffcc) #F15
key.window = key.root = X11.XDefaultRootWindow(display)
X11.XSendEvent(display, key.window, True, 1, ctypes.byref(key))
X11.XCloseDisplay(display)
```

This minimal example worked well for me (just using `F2` instead). The same can be done to send a `KeyRelease` event. If a special window is to be targeted, `key.window` should be set appropriately.

I'm not sure, if it's necessary to use the `XEvent` union, since it'd worked with the `XKeyEvent` all alone for me, but it's better to be safe.

Comment: this sadly does not seem to work for me... ctypes seem to be finding the library in the right path, but something is failing silently unfortunately