# ctypes and XPeekIfEvent for XMotionEvent: Segmentation faults

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, x11, ctypes

I'm having problems doing `XPeekIfEvent` from `libX11`,
The second time it is called I get a segmentation fault.
This happens when I add the `send_event` to the struct.

If you see a `@NOTE` in the code, it is a note from me to you.

The entire code is available here: https://github.com/Centril/sublime-autohide-sidebar/blob/9f3e505c1b78a474de569299fddb704e3dc77d8f/x.py

The relevant documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html
- https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html
- https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structures.html#XEvent
- https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XPeekIfEvent.html
- http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libx11-ddefs.html

The relevant C/C++ definitions from `Xlib.h` and `X.h`:

```cpp
// X.h
typedef unsigned long XID;
typedef XID Window;
typedef CARD32 XID;
typedef CARD32 Time;
typedef XID Window;

// Xlib.h
#define Bool int

typedef struct _XDisplay Display;
struct _XDisplay;       /* Forward declare before use for C++ */

typedef struct {
    int type;       /* of event */
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    Bool send_event;    /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
    Display *display;   /* Display the event was read from */
    Window window;          /* "event" window reported relative to */
    Window root;            /* root window that the event occurred on */
    Window subwindow;   /* child window */
    Time time;      /* milliseconds */
    int x, y;       /* pointer x, y coordinates in event window */
    int x_root, y_root; /* coordinates relative to root */
    unsigned int state; /* key or button mask */
    char is_hint;       /* detail */
    Bool same_screen;   /* same screen flag */
} XMotionEvent;
typedef XMotionEvent XPointerMovedEvent;

typedef struct {
    int type;
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    Bool send_event;    /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
    Display *display;/* Display the event was read from */
    Window window;  /* window on which event was requested in event mask */
} XAnyEvent;

/*
 * this union is defined so Xlib can always use the same sized
 * event structure internally, to avoid memory fragmentation.
 */
typedef union _XEvent {
        int type;       /* must not be changed; first element */
    XAnyEvent xany;
    XKeyEvent xkey;
    XButtonEvent xbutton;
    XMotionEvent xmotion;
    XCrossingEvent xcrossing;
    XFocusChangeEvent xfocus;
    XExposeEvent xexpose;
    XGraphicsExposeEvent xgraphicsexpose;
    XNoExposeEvent xnoexpose;
    XVisibilityEvent xvisibility;
    XCreateWindowEvent xcreatewindow;
    XDestroyWindowEvent xdestroywindow;
    XUnmapEvent xunmap;
    XMapEvent xmap;
    XMapRequestEvent xmaprequest;
    XReparentEvent xreparent;
    XConfigureEvent xconfigure;
    XGravityEvent xgravity;
    XResizeRequestEvent xresizerequest;
    XConfigureRequestEvent xconfigurerequest;
    XCirculateEvent xcirculate;
    XCirculateRequestEvent xcirculaterequest;
    XPropertyEvent xproperty;
    XSelectionClearEvent xselectionclear;
    XSelectionRequestEvent xselectionrequest;
    XSelectionEvent xselection;
    XColormapEvent xcolormap;
    XClientMessageEvent xclient;
    XMappingEvent xmapping;
    XErrorEvent xerror;
    XKeymapEvent xkeymap;
    XGenericEvent xgeneric;
    XGenericEventCookie xcookie;
    long pad[24];
} XEvent;
```

My code is the following (removed some irrelevant parts...):

```py
# License: GPL2+

# Typedefs:
class Display( Structure ):
    _fields_ = []

Bool = c_int
Time = c_ulong
Atom = c_ulong
#Display = c_int
DisplayPtr = POINTER( Display )
Window = c_ulong
WindowPtr = POINTER( Window )
XPointer = c_char_p

# Typedefs: Structs & Unions & FunPtr:s:
class XAnyEvent( Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', c_int),
        ('serial', c_ulong),
        ('send_event', Bool),
        ('display', DisplayPtr ),
        ('window', Window)
    ]

class XMotionEvent( Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', c_int),
        ('serial', c_ulong),
        ('send_event', Bool),
        ('display', DisplayPtr ),
        ('window', Window),
        ('root', Window),
        ('subwindow', Window),
        ('time', Time),
        ('x', c_int), ('y', c_int),
        ('x_root', c_int), ('y_root', c_int),
        ('state', c_uint),
        ('is_hint', c_char),
        ('same_screen', Bool)
    ]

class XEvent( Union ):
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', c_int),
        ('xany', XAnyEvent),
        ('xmotion', XMotionEvent)
    ]

EventPredicate = CFUNCTYPE( Bool, DisplayPtr, POINTER( XEvent ), XPointer )

# Constants:
MotionNotify = 6
PointerMotionMask = (1 << 6)

# @NOTE: irrelevant parts removed.
# @NOTE: Assume sublimes is a list of X11 Window:s but wrapped.

for w in sublimes: w.select_input( PointerMotionMask )

# NOTE: All of the below really happens in another thread:

def motion_predicate( d, e, a ):
    return e.contents.type == MotionNotify
pred = EventPredicate( motion_predicate )

# Event pump:
atexit.register( self.stop )
event = XEvent()
while self.alive:
    print( "a" )
    print( "#6")
    # NOTE: Here we fail!
    x.XPeekIfEvent( disp, byref( event ), pred, None )
    print( event )
    print( "type", event.type )
    print( "b" )
```

If I remove all fields except for `type` in `XAnyEvent` and `XMotionEvent`
it works, otherwise it fails with either a segmentation fault:

```
window 81788931 pid 2990 title ~/programming/sublime-autohide-sidebar/x.py (sublime-autohide-sidebar) - Sublime Text
window 82632928 pid 2990 title untitled - Sublime Text
#1
#1
<__main__.XEvent object at 0x7f9a873b4bf8>
#2 type 6
#3
#1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Or:

```
window 81788931 pid 2990 title ~/programming/sublime-autohide-sidebar/x.py (sublime-autohide-sidebar) - Sublime Text
window 82632928 pid 2990 title untitled - Sublime Text
#1
*** Error in `python3': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00007fb904001060 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This happens when I actually move the mouse inside one of the windows.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer in this SO post:
[How can I use python xlib to generate a single keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638210/how-can-i-use-python-xlib-to-generate-a-single-keypress)

... I adapted the solution to:

```
class XMotionEvent( Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', c_int),
        ('serial', c_ulong),
        ('send_event', Bool),
        ('display', DisplayPtr ),
        ('window', Window),
        ('root', Window),
        ('subwindow', Window),
        ('time', Time),
        ('x', c_int), ('y', c_int),
        ('x_root', c_int), ('y_root', c_int),
        ('state', c_uint),
        ('is_hint', c_char),
        ('same_screen', Bool)
    ]

class XEvent( Union ):
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', c_int),
        ('xmotion', XMotionEvent),
        ('pad', c_long * 24),
    ]
```

Comment: I [revised](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30281261/revisions) the linked answer to prevent the `Display *` value from being converted to `c_int`. When a function returns a pointer, remember to set its `restype` to a pointer type.

Comment: It's OK for me, I'm not caring about the display at all, so it doesn't matter to me =) But yes, you're right. Regarding XAnyEvent, you can even let XMotionEvent inherit from XAnyEvent in order to reduce TLOC. See: https://github.com/Centril/sublime-autohide-sidebar/commit/32025e611149b064066dede5a8b0dd29cb647df4

Comment: If you never pass `display` back as an argument, that's fine. But otherwise set `restype` to the opaque pointer type that I showed (note that using `c_void_p` instead would require also setting `argtypes`). This is necessary because if a 64-bit pointer is truncated when cast as a 32-bit integer, then code using it will either segfault immediately or corrupt memory and probably segfault some time later.

Comment: Ah, right, forgot that, thanks!